# Why does Guid.NewGuid always have a 4 in the exact same spot?

Tags: .net, random, guid

I created a console application which just generated random GUIDs, but it came to my attention that it keeps having a `4` at the same location... Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim generatedGuids = New List(Of String)
    Dim duplicateGenerated As Boolean = False
    Dim index As ULong = 0

    While Not duplicateGenerated

        Dim generatedGuid As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        generatedGuids.Add(generatedGuid)

        duplicateGenerated = generatedGuids.Count <> generatedGuids.Distinct.Count

        index += 1

        Console.WriteLine(index & " - " & generatedGuid)


    End While

    Console.WriteLine("FOUND A DUPLICATE")

End Sub
```

(It's in VB.Net because I just took some online courses, and was playing around with it.)

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, each generated GUID has a `4` at the exact same spot... Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: [UUID version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random))

Comment: Also, you're not going to [generate a duplicate](https://ericlippert.com/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three/): "on the order 2³⁰ personal computers in the world ... if each one can generate, say, 2²⁰ GUIDs per second ... odds of collision get pretty good after only thirty trillion years."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, just wanted to test it out myself. :P Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all 128 bits of a GUID are random.

This character represents the the UUID version (version 4 in your case), and the four bits of it are not supposed to be random.

There is another one :

The next first character after the next hyphen is not completely random as well, a few bits of it are determined and are actually coding the *variant* of the UUID version.

Notice that in your run, all the values of this last character are greater than or equal to `8`, and less than `c` which means the hexadecimal value has always the first bits at 10 : `10xx`, and it means you are using UUID version 4, variant 1.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier for more info.

And... that's all for the determined bits, so don't worry, your GUIDs are still unique!

Comment: Oh I see, perhaps I should've dug a little bit deeper before asking it here. But thank you for the quick reply!